# How would I go about creating gravity for the Unity Character Controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I’ve been working on a new game with a character controlled by a CharacterController.

```
void Jump()
{

    if (character.isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = 0; 
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && character.isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce* gravity * 3); 
      
        
    }
    
   

    if(character.isGrounded == false)
    {
      velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    character.Move(velocity *Time.deltaTime);

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong with how I'm programming my gravity?

I followed Unity’s tutorial, but it doesn’t work at all. My gravity works, but my character won’t jump when I want it to. It sometimes jumps when I hit space, and sometimes not.

Comment: is there a reason why the built in physics arent enough? I would say Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce* gravity * 3);  is an odd thing to set but, if by moving a fraction the jump would get cancelled if jump is still called

Comment: @BugFinder the [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html) is built-in and more or less works like a very stripped down kinematic Rigidbody, detects/causes collision etc - but doesn't run on forces but instead you have to "manually" move it so you need to/can handle gravity yourself.

Comment: @derHugo tbh i wasnt sure and didnt like to assume it was the unity built in only and not effected by anyone elses or something else.

Comment: @BugFinder I can actually reproduce this quite well with the built-in one ... I would be as disappointed as OP .. the `isGrounded` doesn't seem to be quite reliable here ...

Comment: I also noticed that my character controller is floating above the ground which is the reason why the isGrounded doesn't work. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way you setup, if you run this in update and even if you don't forget to set the isGrounded variable sometimes before it could happen this code snippet may run before setting the isGrounded and cause it to nullify the effect of the jump

```
if (character.isGrounded)
{
    velocity.y = 0; 
}
```

You might want to make sure you update the isGrounded right after you jump and make sure isGrounded doesn't set for a while.
But you should change this approach because handling the grounded state and the velocity of the character should not be affected by the jump. You might have problems if you implement falling from a cliff with this approach in the future.

Comment: So removing that snippet might fix it? I'll try and I'll get back to you with my findings.

Comment: No, you could leave it as is. Just make sure you update isGrounded at the right time. I can not say where you should update it since I don't know where you calculate isGrounded.